# Scala: Edit/Modify json string based on internal value

Tags: json, scala

I have a json string structured similarly to the following:

```
val json : String =
    {
       "identifier":{
          "id":"1234_567_910",
          "timestamp":"12:34:56",
       },
       "information":[
          {
             "fieldName":"test_name",
             "fieldId":"test_fieldId",
          }
       ]
    }
```

What I want to do is create a check that verifies the 'id' field matches the structure "Int_Int_Int" and if it doesn't I want to change the value to match this intended structure but I want to keep the rest of the information in the json string as is.

So if I received the following 'id' fields within a json string I would want to change them like so:

```
"id":"1234_567_910" -> do nothing 
"id":"1234"         -> "id":"1234_0_0"
"id":"1234_567"     -> "id":"1234_567_0"
"id":"1234_???"     -> "id":"1234_0_0"
"id":"1234_??_???"  -> "id":"1234_0_0"
"id":"1234_foo"     -> "id":"1234_0_0"
"id":"1234_567_foo" -> "id":"1234_567_0"
```

For Example:

If I receive json like this:

```
{
   "identifier":{
      "id":"1234",
      "timestamp":"12:34:56",
   },
   "information":[
      {
         "fieldName":"test_name",
         "fieldId":"test_fieldId",
      }
   ]
}
```

I would want to modify it so I end up with a json like this:

```
{
   "identifier":{
      "id":"1234_0_0",
      "timestamp":"12:34:56",
   },
   "information":[
      {
         "fieldName":"test_name",
         "fieldId":"test_fieldId",
      }
   ]
}
```

What would be the most effective/cleanest way to achieve this type of json modification in Scala?

Comment: First, pick a json library. - Second, decide if you want to modify the json itself _(if the picked library supports that)_ or first map it into some case classes, then do the mapping in normal scala and the map the case classes to a json again.  - Third, try to implement that. - Fourth, if you got any problems, that you couldn't solve by googling, open a new and more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how it can be done with the [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) library.

```
import com.github.pathikrit.dijon._

def normalize(id: String): String =
  id.count(_ == '_') match {
    case 0 => id + "_0_0"
    case 1 => id + "_0"
    case _ => id
  }

val json =
  json"""
    {
       "identifier":{
          "id":"1234",
          "timestamp":"12:34:56"
       },
       "information":[
          {
             "fieldName":"test_name",
             "fieldId":"test_fieldId"
          }
       ]
    }"""
json.identifier.id = json.identifier.id.asString.fold("0_0_0")(normalize)
println(pretty(json))
```

It should print:

```
{
  "identifier": {
    "id": "1234_0_0",
    "timestamp": "12:34:56"
  },
  "information": [
    {
      "fieldName": "test_name",
      "fieldId": "test_fieldId"
    }
  ]
}
```